# Requires files in one file - Angular | Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, selenium, protractor

I have question, can I have many requires js files in one file ? If yes, how can I create object from this ?  Calling like new AllPages.OnePage() doesn't working. if it is not clear. 
 I want it like headers in C++, many *.h in one header. Thank you very much!

**testFlow.js**

```
 var AllPages = require("./../requires.js"); 
    describe('Test1', function() { 
         beforeEach(function() {
           new Login().login();
      });
it('Can i do it', function() {

        new AllPages.OnePage()
            .goToHome(Address);
        browser.sleep(10000);
        });
```

**requires.js**

```
var Login = require("./login.js");
var LoginPage = require("./pages/loginPage.js");
var OnePage = require("./pages/onePage.js");
```

**loginPage.js**

```
var LoginPage = function() {
    this.visit = function() {
        browser.get(browser.params.context);
        return this;
    };
    this.enterName = function(name) {
        element(by.id("j_username")).sendKeys(name);
        return this;
    };
    this.enterPswd = function(pswd) {
        element(by.id("j_password")).sendKeys(pswd);
        return this;
    };
    this.login = function() {
        element(by.id("submit")).click();
    };
};

module.exports = LoginPage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using it like below -

**requires.js**

```
module.exports = {
    Login : require('./login.js'),
    Loginpage : require('./pages/loginPage.js') // and so on
};
```

You can then require this `requires.js` in the files you want. You can invoke required files as follows -

```
var ALL  = require('./requires');

// calling Login page functions 
// ALL.Login like this
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to export your requires as a new plugin

/requires/index.js

```
module.exports = {
    Login = require('../login/login.js'),
    Loginpage = require('')
};
```

/testFlow.js

```
const All = require('requires/index.js');
```

Comment: When I use your code for module.exports it's problem in semicolon, if use comma, it's problem in equals between (Login **=** require(' '),

Comment: Yes comma at line 2 and nothing at line 3